# Cannot pass variables to usemutation() in Apollo

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I try to use Apollo's `usemutation()`, but I cannot pass variables well.
Here's my code.

```
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const CREATE_USER = gql(/* GraphQL */ `
    mutation createUserByEmail($hoge: String!) {
        createUserByEmail(input: $hoge) {
            age
            
        }
    }
`);

const [createUser, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);

const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        const response = await createUser({variables: {hoge: 'hoge'}}) ;
    }
```

I get the error like

```
Argument type {variables: {hoge: string}} is not assignable to parameter type MutationFunctionOptions<any, OperationVariables, DefaultContext, ApolloCache<any>> | undefined
```

However, my code is exactly same with [the Apollo's documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/).
Where is wrong in my code?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Best,
Kazuya

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the `gql` helper from the file your codegen autogenerated from you.

Comment: I think I will use graphql codegen after sending any request with easy sample.

Comment: Indeed, I used graphql codegen, but I cannot do any mutation and want to find where my problem is

Comment: You only need to  `import { gql } from '../some/generated/file';` - instead of importing that from `'@apollo/client'`.